# The variance of estimator in comparison with $\text{Var}\left(\hat\beta_{OLS}\right)$

Tags: variance, least-squares, estimators

How could it be shown that the estimator that connects the first and the last observations in a large enough dataset indeed has smaller variance than $\hat\beta_{OLS}$?

Comment: @RichardHardy, it is a slope estimator

Comment: Actually, when we studied it for the model we were writing it with betta and for the result that we derived as a slope estimator we were writing as b.

Comment: The hat over $\beta$ indicates it is an estimator, not the true value. But you can denote it $b$ if you like. I thought it is more consistent if we denote estimators with hats, then there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I always thought the $\hat \beta_{\text{OLS}}$ was the estimator with the least variance?

Comment: @dietervdf Almost, it has the smallest variance among linear, unbiased estimators. Under some assumptions of course.